# JMH: Uneven test in seemingly even setup

Tags: java, jvm, performance-testing, jmh

I was playing around `Math.max` to see if it's affected by branch prediction (no, at least on JDK for x64 it's not, there's a `cmovl`) and if bitwise implementation can compete with default one. All tests look like this:

```java
@Threads(4)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode({Mode.AverageTime, Mode.SampleTime})
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public class CoreMaximum {
    private int[][] corpus;

    @Setup
    public void setUp() {
        corpus = Corpus.create();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void constant(Blackhole blackhole) {
        val arguments = corpus[0];
        for (val payload : corpus) {
            blackhole.consume(arguments[0]);
            blackhole.consume(arguments[1]);
            blackhole.consume(payload[0]);
            blackhole.consume(payload[1]);
            blackhole.consume(Math.max(arguments[0], arguments[1]));
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void random(Blackhole blackhole) {
        val payload = corpus[0];
        for (val arguments : corpus) {
            blackhole.consume(arguments[0]);
            blackhole.consume(arguments[1]);
            blackhole.consume(payload[0]);
            blackhole.consume(payload[1]);
            blackhole.consume(Math.max(arguments[0], arguments[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

where `Math.max` can be substituted with a call to another implementation, and `Corpus.create()` returns an `int[1_000_000][2]` populated by SecureRandom.

The problem is, even though i'm certainly that called code is not affected by branch prediction and while performing even amount of loads and consumptions in `constant` and `random` benchmarks, i still get similar disparity for benchmarks for all implementations:

```
CoreMaximum.constant                               avgt     25         13.080 ±        0.680  ms/op
CoreMaximum.constant:CPI                           avgt      5          0.528 ±        0.027   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:L1-dcache-load-misses         avgt      5     478734.008 ±     2419.011   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:L1-dcache-loads               avgt      5   49990187.380 ±   114908.845   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:L1-dcache-stores              avgt      5   17998192.002 ±    42008.496   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:L1-icache-load-misses         avgt      5       2142.398 ±      526.619   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:LLC-load-misses               avgt      5      28553.636 ±     1338.175   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:LLC-loads                     avgt      5      33148.939 ±      667.526   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:LLC-store-misses              avgt      5        150.218 ±       26.488   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:LLC-stores                    avgt      5        271.536 ±      113.444   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:branch-misses                 avgt      5        187.060 ±      123.697   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:branches                      avgt      5   17001028.964 ±    32923.938   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:cycles                        avgt      5   57063715.464 ±  2900664.885   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:dTLB-load-misses              avgt      5      13153.047 ±     1808.179   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:dTLB-loads                    avgt      5   49999483.367 ±    94718.665   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:dTLB-store-misses             avgt      5         36.217 ±        7.357   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:dTLB-stores                   avgt      5   17999664.120 ±    23160.612   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:iTLB-load-misses              avgt      5         32.138 ±        4.584   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:iTLB-loads                    avgt      5         16.571 ±       20.613   #/op
CoreMaximum.constant:instructions                  avgt      5  107989860.816 ±   240202.175   #/op
CoreMaximum.random                                 avgt     25         14.082 ±        0.717  ms/op
CoreMaximum.random:CPI                             avgt      5          0.503 ±        0.037   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:L1-dcache-load-misses           avgt      5     479117.110 ±     2632.690   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:L1-dcache-loads                 avgt      5   56030755.475 ±   120501.598   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:L1-dcache-stores                avgt      5   24015559.169 ±    51480.836   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:L1-icache-load-misses           avgt      5       2473.731 ±      968.508   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:LLC-load-misses                 avgt      5      29106.351 ±     1251.508   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:LLC-loads                       avgt      5      34274.838 ±     1178.339   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:LLC-store-misses                avgt      5        156.975 ±       29.332   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:LLC-stores                      avgt      5        268.092 ±      128.106   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:branch-misses                   avgt      5        169.811 ±      102.783   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:branches                        avgt      5   18007736.925 ±    42002.060   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:cycles                          avgt      5   61431988.502 ±  4506086.004   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:dTLB-load-misses                avgt      5      13157.184 ±     1496.518   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:dTLB-loads                      avgt      5   56026614.485 ±   144375.149   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:dTLB-store-misses               avgt      5         37.321 ±        6.870   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:dTLB-stores                     avgt      5   24011292.571 ±    54348.034   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:iTLB-load-misses                avgt      5         38.059 ±       19.549   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:iTLB-loads                      avgt      5         18.290 ±       36.399   #/op
CoreMaximum.random:instructions                    avgt      5  122045528.539 ±   313318.615   #/op
```

(I don't have enough experience to jump to conclusions, but obviously `random` benchmark has a higher number of counters than `constant`, most notably `instructions` and `branches`)

`Random` always takes longer and has more instructions, which obviously tells that the benchmark doesn't account for something, but I don't know what's wrong. I didn't tweak anything but thread count (don't know why, but it was using just one instead of number of cores), warmups should do their work (i see that `C2` already compiles code on the first warmup), and dumping `ASM` (using print in `CompileCommandFile`) doesn't show significant differences besides couple of nops and placement of particular instructions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

While it is still complete mystery to me what was the root cause (probably ASM listings contain the answer, but i don't have enough time to dig through all of them), i think i found the issue. Removing the for loop did the job:

```java
@Threads(4)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class CoreMaximum {
    @Param({"true", "false"})
    public boolean constant;

    private int[][] corpus;

    @Setup
    public void setUp() {
        corpus = constant ? Corpus.constant() : Corpus.random();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void run(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[0][0], corpus[0][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[1][0], corpus[1][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[2][0], corpus[2][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[3][0], corpus[3][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[4][0], corpus[4][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[5][0], corpus[5][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[6][0], corpus[6][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[7][0], corpus[7][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[8][0], corpus[8][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[9][0], corpus[9][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[10][0], corpus[10][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[11][0], corpus[11][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[12][0], corpus[12][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[13][0], corpus[13][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[14][0], corpus[14][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[15][0], corpus[15][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[16][0], corpus[16][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[17][0], corpus[17][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[18][0], corpus[18][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[19][0], corpus[19][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[20][0], corpus[20][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[21][0], corpus[21][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[22][0], corpus[22][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[23][0], corpus[23][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[24][0], corpus[24][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[25][0], corpus[25][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[26][0], corpus[26][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[27][0], corpus[27][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[28][0], corpus[28][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[29][0], corpus[29][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[30][0], corpus[30][1]));
        blackhole.consume(Math.max(corpus[31][0], corpus[31][1]));
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark                              (constant)  Mode  Cnt     Score    Error  Units
CoreMaximum.run                              true  avgt   25    92.235 ±  7.998  ns/op
CoreMaximum.run:CPI                          true  avgt    5     0.392 ±  0.049   #/op
CoreMaximum.run:instructions                 true  avgt    5  1000.988 ±  5.330   #/op
CoreMaximum.run                             false  avgt   25    92.556 ±  9.010  ns/op
CoreMaximum.run:CPI                         false  avgt    5     0.390 ±  0.074   #/op
CoreMaximum.run:instructions                false  avgt    5   999.559 ±  5.132   #/op
```

I'm manually unrolling the loop since single-shot benchmark would have no reason to branch, and introducing direct calls to `Random`/`SecureRandom` in benchmark would probably outweigh the actual implementation call and is too error-prone. And, honestly, removing the actual test subject and checking the results should have been the first thing to do when facing such an issue.

For folks that end up here through google: when you see that you have some error in tests and don't have time to fully dig through, you *can cheat away*. If you are sure that some part of your benchmark is lying, you can try to figure out what part is it and rewrite your benchmark to get rid of it. **But do remember that a) getting numbers you want to see does not prove anything and is rather comforting you than actually confirming a hypothesis and b) if you want to do things *properly*, you have to find out the root cause, otherwise your benchmark is just an escape, that (again) probably hides an error.** I'm cheating out this time only because a) i'm not doing a part of my job and more playing rather than chasing a particular problem in production code, having not enough time for proper investigation and b) i'm sure in results because i've seen ASM listings for all implementations, and the actual implementation i was after - the library one - is just a handful of instructions all of which exclude possibility of branch prediction. **If it's part of your job to find exact answers, don't cheat out, you wont solve the problem you were looking for.**